# Можно ли зашивать коннектор jdbc в программу?

Tags: java, база-данных

Есть небольшое приложение, в котором предоставляется выбор базы данных для дальнейшей работы с программой. Чтоб реализовать такую функциональность, я планирую "зашить" в программу соответствующие коннекторы. [image: BIND]
Из перечисленного списка, на практике знаком с MySql, бегло ознакомился с PostgreSQL, Cassandra и Microsoft. Теоретически, никаких проблем с такой функциональностью не должно быть. С точки зрения практики, хотел бы услышать мнение профессионалов: Можно ли зашивать коннектор jdbc в программу?

*p.s.: названия полей зашифрованы неправильным английским* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если под коннектором JDBC понимается драйвер JDBC, то их включение в комплект программы - это нормальная практика. Но, конечно, при условии, что соблюдаются требования лицензионных соглашений соответствующий драйверов.

И с практической точки зрения желательно предусмотреть возможность обновления драйверов JDBC, например, путём замены соответствующего jar-файла в составе программы. Если программа будет жить достаточно долго, то это пригодится по мере выхода новых версий драйверов JDBC.